# Quickly: how do I return entered data into parent window?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly

at last I started a simple project (you tube video downloader) in quickly , But got stucked  . I added youtube url entry dialog using quickly add dialog command and ;linked it to new button . How  return url to the main window ? I don't have any previous experiance with python

My program now look like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your code, you could do something like this:

```
url = None
dialog = UrlDialog()
response = dialog.run()
if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    url = dialog.get_url()
dialog.destroy()
```

Then just implement a get_url() method or url property in your dialog class:

```
class UrlDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
    # Init etc...

    def get_url(self):
        return self.urlentry.get_text()
```

Comment: Thanks now it shows 

 File "/home/aboobacker/mytube2/mytube2/Mytube2Window.py", line 34, in on_newurlbutton_clicked
    url = dialog.get_url()
  File "/home/aboobacker/mytube2/mytube2/NewurlDialog.py", line 61, in get_url
    return self.newurlentry.get_text()
AttributeError: 'NewurlDialog' object has no attribute 'newurlentry'

What does it mean ?