# Python - access variable in another class

Tags: application-development, quickly, pygtk

I have 1 main window and 1 dialog.
Now I need to access variable in main window from dialog.

For example in java we have 2 classes:
demo and
myclass
In my class I have following code:
    public static int number=5;
Then I simply access it using myclass.number.

How to do it in python using quickly ide?

Do I need to import main window in dialog to get access to static variable?

Comment: I have no idea what quickly is but first of all you wouldn't normally declare a variable public in Java but private (or protected). Second I think that in python you would do import myclass in your other class, then you would instantiate it m=myclass() and should be able to access it m.number. You can also acccess it without instantiation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python for further information.

Comment: To make example more simple I put public :D

Answer (score 1):

Just pass around your mainwindow instance, something like this:

```
class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        # Do your thing...

        self.spam = "spam'n'eggs"

    def on_opendialog_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = MyDialog(self)
        dialog.run()
        dialog.destroy()

class MyDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, mainwindow):
        # ...

        print(mainwindow.spam)
```

Have a look at my answer in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158558/quickly-how-do-i-return-entered-data-into-parent-window/158609#158609) too which is almost similar, only the other way around.

Comment: Error is on line: dialog = MyDialog(self)

Comment: Here you can see the code generated by quickly which probably causes error: http://pastebin.com/68fNcMdD

Comment: Please provide an actual traceback. "Probably" and "error" aren't of any help.

Comment: TypeError: Must be string, not SampleWindow
Here you can find sample application: http://ubuntuone.com/5eCaimCkGxOJn1SxUTTh5T

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the "pro" way to do it or not, but you can pass it to your variable when you generate it.

I have a file generation dialog I built by giving it the default output dir and default name of file. My code looks like:`def __init__(self,parent,output_dir,filename)`, and when you call it make sure to pass it what it needs, eg. `window(output_dir,filename)`

Comment: Here is my code:http://ubuntuone.com/5eCaimCkGxOJn1SxUTTh5T I dont have init